# Working curl query to GraphQL gives 403 in Insomnia and Postman

Tags: curl, graphql, insomnia

I followed the first part of [this](https://serverless.com/blog/make-serverless-graphql-api-using-lambda-dynamodb/) tutorial (until code snippet 4) on GraphQL and serverless.

After deploying the serverless application to AWS I query GraphQL using curl, as shown in snippet 4 of the tutorial and get a response as expected:

```
$ curl -G 'https://example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/query' --data-urlencode 'query={greeting(firstName: "Jeremy")}'
{"data":{"greeting":"Hello, Jeremy."}}
```

**My problem is** that when I attempt to make the same query with either Insomnia or Postman, I get `403 error`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**In Insomnia:**

[image: Insomnia error]

**In Postman**
[image: Postman error]

Comment: For postman, I think you need to add your query request to the request body - this is the only way I was able to get postman to work with AWS AppSync.

Comment: The query request is added to the body of the request already. I used Postman to interpret the curl command with File->Import->Raw Text and pasted the working curl command

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

While I never got Insomnia to work, I got Postman working.

Turns out that while the configuration in the Postman screenshot I included is correct, I simply forgot that I still had content in the body of the request, which caused the error.

So: Make sure that no query is included in Body if you want to make a GET request

[image: Make sure that no query is included in Body]

Answer (score 0):

To query from Insomnia:

1. Have an empty body
2. In the query tab, add a `query` property with your GraphQL query
3. In the Header tab, add a `x-api-key` property with your api key